# How to extract EXTRA_PARAMETER data during PARAMETER_RECEIVED event?

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android

Using Dronekit Android, I'm listening to events in onDroneEvent.  One of those events is AttributeEvent.PARAMETER_RECEIVED

I'm able to get other attributes, like attitude, battery, signal rssi, etc.  Just don't know how to get access to the parameters sent from the drone after connecting.

```
public void onDroneEvent(String event, Bundle extras) {
        switch (event) {
            case AttributeEvent.PARAMETER_RECEIVED:
                //Grab extra parameter data
                //possibly using AttributeEventExtra.EXTRA_PARAMETER_NAME
                // AttributeEventExtra.EXTRA_PARAMETER_INDEX
                // AttributeEventExtra.EXTRA_PARAMETER_VALUE
                break;
. . . removed extraneous code . . .
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look a how this is done in the [Parameter screen](https://github.com/DroidPlanner/Tower/blob/4a54f89196743826a68ca984dca3b729e9f04459/Android/src/org/droidplanner/android/fragments/ParamsFragment.java) in [Tower](https://github.com/DroidPlanner/Tower) for reference.

In general, parameters from the drone are sent after connection, or after an explicit call to [VehicleApi#refreshParameters()](http://android.dronekit.io/javadoc/com/o3dr/android/client/apis/VehicleApi.html#refreshParameters()).

To monitor when they are being refreshed, you can listen for the [PARAMETERS_REFRESH_STARTED](http://android.dronekit.io/javadoc/com/o3dr/services/android/lib/drone/attribute/AttributeEvent.html#PARAMETERS_REFRESH_STARTED) and [PARAMETERS_REFRESH_COMPLETED](http://android.dronekit.io/javadoc/com/o3dr/services/android/lib/drone/attribute/AttributeEvent.html#PARAMETERS_REFRESH_COMPLETED) events. Between these two events, several [PARAMETER_RECEIVED](http://android.dronekit.io/javadoc/com/o3dr/services/android/lib/drone/attribute/AttributeEvent.html#PARAMETER_RECEIVED) events will also be sent for each parameter that's updated.

You can also access the last retrieved set of parameters using:

`Parameters parameters = drone.getAttribute(AttributeType.PARAMETERS);`

Comment: I looked at the Tower reference for what happens during PARAMETER_RECEIVED event, and it appears that it's just updating a progress indicator.  I will definitely try the drone.getAttribute(AttributeType.PARAMETERS) and see if that gets the most recent parameter during that event.